# How can I convert the following optimization problem to a QCQP. minimize ||Gx − h||4.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Minimize over variable x.
G is an n*n matrix.
h is an n*1 vector.
I want to map the equation ||Gx − h||4 is a QCQP problem. OR Map the 4-norm of equation (Gx-h) as QCQP.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Using https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/powo.html#norm-cones you can express any p-norm cone using power cones, and for $p=4$ you will be able to formulate them using a few auxiliary quadratic cones and end up with an SOCP.